# Disable all outbound network

Tags: ubuntu, networking, bash

I cannot seem to find any information on how to completely disable all networking. Essentially I want to flip the switch for any outbound or inbound networking. Like the wifi button on my computer, when I switch that nothing can come in and nothing can go out. The only thing I can think of (but I don't know if it will work) is this:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
```

Will this do the trick?

Comment: Just pull the network cable?

Comment: @Sven I don't have access to those.

Comment: Then how do you plan to turn it back on? Or control the server in any form?

Comment: @Sven I don't have to SSH into the machine. It is a docker container that I have direct access to.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the following commands: (this is to disable all Internet Connections in Ubuntu)

```
nmcli nm enable false
```

and to enable it again:

```
nmcli nm enable true
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

## Down the Network Interface

Without knowing what version of Ubuntu you're running, probably the simplest thing you could do is to just bring down the network interface (assuming you've only got one):

```
sudo ifdown eth0
```

Use the following to bring it back up:

```
sudo ifup eth0
```